# Calling a script within a script that was run via nohup

Tags: bash, nohup

I have a script, which when I run to screen, works perfectly.
The directory structure is as follows:

```
/home/username/processing/ScriptRunning
/home/username/processing/functions/include_me
```

In the script, it opens another script, which contains a function by simply doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is ScriptRunning script
. functions/include_me
```

Now when I call the script using the following nohup command:

nohup /home/username/processing/ScriptRunning

this is the output:

```
/home/username/processing/ScriptRunning: line 3: /home/username/functions/include_me: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be missing out the `processing` directory

I've altered the line within the `ScriptRunning` to have a full path, both hardcoded to `/home/username/processing` and also having this as a variable created by calling `$(pwd)`, but the error is the same.

Am I really missing something so stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a `nohup` issue. You are including a source file using a relative file name. Try:

```sh
. $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE})/functions/include_me
```

to include a source file located relative to `${BASH_SOURCE}`

Comment: I'm such an idiot, its just me, what a donkey! I didn't realise the nohup.out was being appended to. The first error was the initial and there was a different after that. Your answer does work, I was doing something very similar myself in setting a variable using $(dirname). I'm so sorry to have wasted your time, what a clown I am